# How can I enable RPC protocol on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, rpc

I tried

```
#rpcinfo
```

but I don't get any useful informations. In fedora it's enabled by default, but it's not the same in ubuntu.

How can I make it work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

Install package **rpcbind** using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install rpcbind
```

After that **rpcinfo** is available.

Comment: The link above is now broken, does anyone know the context to what this link contained?